# limit remote sender attachment file size on exim

Tags: linux, email, exim

I have Cpanel related to exim mail server.

I want to refuse any email from sender which has attachment size over 15 MB.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

- Go to WHM -> Main -> Service Configuration -> Exim Configuration Editor
- At the bottom, click on "Advanced Editor"
- put the line : **message_size_limit = 15M** on the first text box
- Click on save.

Message size limit not actually limits attachment(s) only size, but...

Comment: Are you sure? This parameter is a Postfix parameter and not an Exim one.

Comment: @mailq, Exim too.  http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch14.html

Comment: thanks for help ^_^
message_size_limit = 15M
Its work fine

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
message_size_limit = 15M
```

to the exim.conf. And This line can be added below this line:

```
message_body_visible = 5000
```